# Trying to do an update after user insert data in wp database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to update a column in WP database after user registers or after insert.

I am now trying to get the last inserted ID that I want to use in the where clause and update the column which its value is from a url.

```
if ( empty( $userdata['user_login'] ) ) {
    $part_of_email          = explode( '@', $userdata['user_email'] );
    $username               = check_username( $part_of_email[0] );
    $userdata['user_login'] = $username;
}
global $wpdb;
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ); // Insert user data in users table.
    $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
//$table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."users";
$where = array('ID' => $lastid );
$subs = array('refID'=> $_GET['ref']);
$wpdb->update('users', $subs, $where);
```

Comment: ... and your question/problem is?

Comment: I just need help if I am doing anything wrong because it doesn't want to update

Comment: One thing I noticed: shouldn't `if ( empty( $userdata['user_login'] ) ) {` be `if ( ! empty( $userdata['user_login'] ) ) {` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use update_user_meta function.

```
// Will return false if the previous value is the same as $new_value.
$updated = update_user_meta( $user_id, 'refID', $_GET['ref']  );
```